# Как сработает список в боте ТГ

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Хочу создать некий тест в боте ТГ. Вопрос, ответ и результат планирую записать в формате json, что бы удобно было сохранять и выдавать результаты, но есть непонимание логики одного момента. Вот отстранённой пример. В начале теста создаю пустой список. Потом том начинаю записывать в него результаты прохождения теста. В конце вывожу итог. И вот вопрос - если 2 человека запустят прохождение теста одновременно для каждого будет свой data или у меня всё смешается в кашу или изначально пустой список лучше назвать по имени проходящего к примеру?

```
data = {}
data['num_q'] = []
data['num_q'].append({
    'question': 'Scott',
    'ansver': 'pythonist.ru',
    'result': 'Nebraska'
})

data['num_q'].append({
    'question': 'Larry',
    'ansver': 'pythonist.ru',
    'result': 'Michigan'
})

data['num_q'].append({
    'question': 'Tim',
    'ansver': 'pythonist.ru',
    'result': 'Alabama'
})
with open(f'{name_recipient}.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: как напишите так и будет, нам то откуда знать как вы будете обрабатывать данные пользователей...

Comment: Вообще не о том вопрос был! Вопрос был именно о data. Если я оставлю просто data без изменений для каждого запуска это будет свой объект или если запустить параллельно то 2 пользователя бота будут в него одновременно писать и начнутся проблемы.

Comment: Будут проблемы. Там где файл сохраняете - там будут проблемы.

Comment: сохранение идёт вот так with open(f'{name_recipient}.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile). Те к каждому имени файла дописывается имя проходящего тест. Плюс добавлю скорее всего временную метку через datatime. Беспокойство вызывает только начальный объект data

Comment: Каждая запущенная программа живет в своей изолированной памяти, ваш скрипт не исключение, у каждой его запущенной копии значения переменных будут индивидуальны для каждой копии.

Comment: Спасибо! В этом и хотел удостовериться.